# Pairwise comparison

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to execute a statement in SQL Server based on parameter `@p` that is passed into my stored procedure when it's called.

If `@p` has value 1, then data from table `[a]` is not filtered, if `@p` has value 0, then data from table `[a]` is filtered based on data on table `[b]`. But data must be compared using pair comparison.

If SQL Server support pairwise comparison, I can do this by using this syntax

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    a
WHERE
    (@p = 1) or ((a.col1, a.col2) in (SELECT col1, col2 FROM b))
```

but, unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support pairwise comparison.

I can also do it by using if statement.

```
if(@p=1)
begin
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        a
end
else
begin
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        a join b on a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2
end
```

but, it makes my stored procedure too long. Is there another workaround to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest method is with the EXISTS syntax:

```
SELECT columnlist
FROM a
WHERE @p=1 OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.col1=b.col1 AND a.col2=b.col2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be rewritten like this using EXISTS:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
a
WHERE
(@p = 1) or EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM b where b.col1=a.col1 and b.col2=a.col2)
```